# alarmManager approach to update data every 10 mins

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I tried using

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable(){

            public void run() {
                // update server  (method which has asyncTask)
            }

        }, 0, 600, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

And it stops working after mobile sleeps. I would like to do the same using alarmManager but I dont know if  I should use service,broadcast service or activity for the requirement above.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Activity/Service/BroadcastReceiver will depend on what "update server" means to you, and what kind of code will be executed in there. Do you need a background Thread? Notification? UI? ContentProvider? Take a look at the AlarmManager docs to learn how to schedule an execution. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: @RobertEstivill Thanks you Sir for the reply .Update server is a method which has asyncTask .It will update the data of users location,check if new messages have arrived in the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are going to be networking, i would recommend you to use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). If you don't need to keep state in between executions, or don't want to deal with threads manually, use an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)

This is the code i'm using to set up the a polling service:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent( context, YourService.class );
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService( context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService( ALARM_SERVICE );
    alarmManager.setRepeating( AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, POLLING_INTERVAL, POLLING_START_DELAY, pendingIntent );
```

Comment: Thank You Sir for looking into it. Can you please explain in detail .I did not get the part "state in between executions" probably with examples or links.Also after the above code runs in background it should not open the app .It should still be in home screen or whichever screen/App the user was in when he put his mobile to sleep.Thank You again.

Comment: "State in between executions" means that you are storing the information received in some way other than a service variable, so the service instance can be killed and re instantiate on the next alarm. The IntentService has a one execution cycle, so unless you use static attributes, will not mantain any state in between it's executions.

Comment: I am storing the data which I receive via async using json.Ad also it updates the class which hold global values of notificcation count.

Comment: Please can you give me source code for the above requirement or any link for the same.Thank You Sir for your time.It helped me a lot.

Comment: Well, i bet that json is parsed into an object. If that object is not part of the service, IntentService will work just fine.

Comment: I have never used IntentService till now.I receive json as string .Please let me know How do I go about it.Will the code you provided in the answer work?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent( context, YourService.class ); in the code will open that class right ? I dont want it to open any app .It should happen in the background.

Comment: What happens if I quit the app will the service still run?

Comment: It will fire YourService.class ( it needs to extend IntentService and be declared on the manifest ). The alarm manager will fire your service no matter what's the state of the app, running, foreground, background or stopped.

Comment: Then How do I stop the service if the app s killed by dragging out from recent apps or force stop from settings ? Please let me know .